# clickable image inside for loop

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

My problem is that my site has a page that loops through all of your uploaded images and I made them links with `a` tag outside the `img` tag.

How can the linked page know which picture was `clicked` on in order to display the `image` on that page without the ability to send variables back to the server?

As you can see in my html code below.  I am using `node.js` with `ejs`

```
<div id="photofeed">
    <% if(photo!=null) {%>
        <% for(i=imgcount-1;i>=0;i--) {%>
            <div id="photo">
                <a href="photomenu"><img src="<%= photo[i].photo.path %>" width="200" height="200"></img></a>
                <h4><%= photo[i].photo.name%></h4>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: You already have the link to the image while you creating the a tag just use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer since I don't have enough reputation to comment. From what I understand, you have a set of images that all link to the same page, 'photomenu'. Since all the images are being displayed in the same page, you cannot use the previous page (the one in which you clicked the image) to see which picture was clicked since it will be the same for all pictures. What you can do is pass a query parameter in the URL as use that as a reference of which picture was clicked.

For example, if you have two photos, each photo would redirect to `photomenu?photo=photo_id`. You can use the `photo_id` value when you load the new page to know which picture was clicked.

Comment: I tried and I couldn't get the photo_id to show up in the url.  do I need to use jquery for this because I don't know how to use it

Comment: @justin you do not need to use jQuery. How are you generating the `photomenu` page? You'll have to handle this in the request handler for that particular page.

Answer (score 0):

> You just need to change here a bit. Just pas Photo Id in query string.

```
<a href="photomenu?id="+photo[i].photo.Id ><img src="<%= photo[i].photo.path %>" width="200" height="200"></img></a>
```

> Now The Linked page will be having this code

```
int PhotoID = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

> Now you need to display the Image...

```
<img src = "imageSrc\"+PhotoID alt="Image"/>
```